VSCode: Quick Open (Cmd-P) fuzzy match stopped working correctly
When doing a quick open (Cmd-P) in VSCode, the fuzzy search of file names stopped working yesterday for me.
Searching for 'notet' matches file 'note.svelte', but not file 'note.ts'. Searching for just 'note' matches both files.
Also, I previously could search with pathnames included, like 'engnote' to find file 'engraver/note.svelte', but that also stopped working.
I updated to 1.93.1 yesterday. It might be related to the update, but I'm 100% sure the problem started at that moment, or if it was before/after. I have of course restarted both VSCode and the whole computer and verified that the problem still exists.

cannot repro with 1.93.1 on Ubuntu with deb install. Please copy and paste the output of the Help: About command (run in the command palette) into your question post.
